# ¿Que estoy haciendo mal en este codigo?

Tags: c, matriz

Quiero imprimir la siguiente matriz:

```
1  2  3  4  5

2  1  2  3  4 

3  2  1  2  3 

4  3  2  1  2 
 
5  4  3  2  1
```

Pero no se que esta mal en este código, no he encontrado una solucion, hasta ahora solo he conseguido hacer que imprima bien la parte de arriba en diagonal pero la de abajo no, imprime ceros y numeros negativos no se a que se debe. :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n=0;
    int count=0;
    int count2=0;
    
    printf("Digite numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int matriz[n][n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        
        for(int j=0;j<=n;++j){
            
            count=i+1;
            matriz[i][j]=count;
            
        }   
        
        for(int j=n;j>0;--j){
            
            matriz[i][j]=count2;
            count2=j-i;
        }   

    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
            
            printf("%3d",matriz[i][j]);
            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: que recorre i? y espues que recorren ls os j? no es ms facil, llenar cada fila?

Comment: Pues i recorre las filas, y los 2 for son para que queden las columnas como se ve en la matriz, lo cual no he podido hacer

Comment: tenes que recorrer 5 elementos no... primero para abajo hasta llegar a 1, y luego para arriba... entonces.. tenes un for por filas.. y despues un for por columnas que va de 1 a 5 siempre.. y una variable.. que baja y sube segun tu necesidad... no?

Comment: Diria que si pero el tercer for esta mal, no creo que se deba aplicar de esa forma

Comment: ese for.. sobra totalmente con lo que te dije.. te alcanza con 2 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("Digite numero: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int matriz[n][n];
```

Para empezar, `matriz` es un VLA o (Variable Length Array). Es decir un array cuyo tamaño viene dado por una variable. Esta característica no está soportada por el estándar desde el año 1999. Tu compilador tienes la suerte que lo soporta, pero podría suceder que en otro entorno (tu casa, en clase, ...) deje de hacerlo.

Para esta tarea debes usar memoria dinámica:

```
int **matriz = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
  matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Este diseño te permite usar una matriz con dos índices. Aunque, por otro lado, para lo que quieres hacer no es necesario usar una matriz.

> imprime ceros y numeros negativos no se a que se debe

Lógico y normal. Si te fijas, estás escribiendo la matriz dos veces:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
    
    for(int j=0;j<=n;++j){ // primera
        
        count=i+1;
        matriz[i][j]=count;
        
    }   
    
    for(int j=n;j>0;--j){ // segunda
        
        matriz[i][j]=count2;
        count2=j-i;
    }   

}
```

Además las iteraciones son incorrectas ya que en C los arrays empiezan en `0` y terminan en la posición `n-1`. Así, la primera iteración está escribiendo en la posición `n`, lo cual es incorrecto, y la segunda iteración aparte de escribir en `n`,  deja intacta la posición `0`.

El caso, aparte de esos errores, es que la segunda iteración va a sobreescribir los valores que ha generado la primera iteración y aquí viene la respuesta a tu duda, fíjate:

```
for(int j=n;j>0;--j){
    matriz[i][j]=count2;
    count2=j-i; // <<--- AQUI
}
```

¿Qué sucede cuando `i>j`? En la fila `0` sucede que `i` vale 0, luego no va a ser mayor que `j`, pero en la última fila, `i=4`, `j` tendrá, por ejemplo, el valor 0 y `0-4=-4`. Ya tienes el origen de los números negativos.

Tienes que evitar que ambos bucles se solapen, que escriban fuera de los límites del array y que asignen los valores esperados:

```
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
{
    for( int j=i; j>0; j-- )
    {
      printf("%d ", j+1);
    }

    for( int j=1; j<=n-i; j++ )
    {
      printf("%d ", j);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Por cierto, nota como la matriz se está imprimiendo sin necesidad de usar un array

Answer (score 0):

Una forma, en este caso utilizando funciones matematicas (abs), podria ser la siguiente:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(j=1; j<=n; j++){
        printf("%d ", (abs(j-i)+1) );
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

en realidad, el problema se resuelve con dos bucles que se incrementan de uno en uno, cada uno independiente. Lo que imprimes es el resultado de restar el valor del interior (en este ejemplo, la variable j) con el valor del exterior (i).

la resta te va a dar negativa, puesto que en la primera iteracion i=1 y j=1, quedandote 0. en la segunda iteracion del bucle interior, i=1 y j=2, por lo que 1-2=-1... pero al pasar por la funcion abs, este se convierte en positivo (1).

El incremento de +1 que se hace en la impresion, es para ajustar los valores, para que sean los que esperas.